# React/Redux changing values in module (not in component)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to do ca. this: I have my module httpService using axios to work on communication with API. In short it looks like this:

```
import axios from "axios";

function post(url, dt) {
  const ret = axios.post(url, dt).then(true);
  return ret;
}

export default {
  get: axios.get,
  post,
  put: axios.put,
  delete: axios.delete
};
```

And I want to show "somehow" in application in some component, that some axios request is running. My basic idea is, that I can use Redux to save state of post function. I know how to show (and change) Redux values in component (in my case some info panel in app - for example just loading icon), but I don't know how to change state from my post function mentioned above, witch is not part of component...

Again basic (not contain what if error happend etc.) sample what I want as result:

```
function post(url, dt) {
  SET STATE TO SHOW LOADING ICON
  const ret = axios.post(url, dt).then(HIDE LOADING ICON);
  return ret;
}
```

My question is, if this is good way how to indicate in app, that axios is running (if there is any smarter solution). And if this is good idea, then how to do it just on module function, not on component. Thank you for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

No need to use redux in this case, however if you are set on it feel free to take this answer in that direction.

`axios.post` is returning a promise. So rather than doing your `.then()` in the function you can do it in your component. Here is a sample using hooks for a loading indicator.

```
import * as React from 'react'
const {useState} = React

const FormPage = () => {
    const [loadingActive, setLoadingActive] = useState(false)
    // we are now loading, 
    // this could be triggered just before firing the post function
    setLoadingActive(true)

    post('http://example.com', {randomData: 1}).then((resultData) => 
        setLoadingActive(false))
    .catch((error) => {
        // handle the error
        setLoadingActive(false)
    })

    <>
        <Loader show={loadingActive} />

        <div>other stuff</div>
    </>

}
```

So the post function would not call `.then` inside of it and instead it would just `return` the promise. You can use `async/await` or the `promise.then().catch()` syntax. Whichever you feel more comfortable with. They will get called once the request has completed. `.catch` is called if an error happens and `.then` if it is successful. `.then`'s function will receive the data sent back down as the result which you are able to use.

make sure your call the `setLoadingActive` in either the `.then` or `.catch` or `.finally` - more info on `.finally` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally

Comment: also, just re read the post title... oops. Look into redux promise, redux thunk or redux saga. Either of those deal with asynchronous requests.